# Run -> Exception not available in in Mono Develop 5.7

Tags: mono, monodevelop

In Mono Develop 3.X, there is a menu option to configure exceptions we wish to break on (Run -> Exceptions).
But with Mono Develop 5.7 IDE it is no longer there?
Also Debugger is not breaking on exceptions.

Any idea How to get it back, probably some add-ins ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exception catchpoints are now in same dialog as breakpoints.
You can open this dialog via

- Run->New Exception Catchpoint
- Breakpoints pad has button "New Exception Catchpoint"

What is nice about this is, you can use conditional and counting filters and different conditions/counts for different exceptions and also print debugging text(tracepoint) instead of breaking.

Most common use case is to add "System.Exception" and check "Include subclasses".